# How to define the button's font based on the screen size in xcode

Tags: ios, autolayout, font-size

I don't think there is a mechanism to define the font for buttons based on the screen size?
Below is an example of the issue with a sliding menu. iPhone 7 first:
[image]

and with the SE:

[image]

so I need to get the device model and calculate the font to apply programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use size classes.

1. Click on + near Font in Attribute inspector.
2. Choose regular & regular for IPAD
3. OR choose compact width and regular height for Iphone.
4. OR you can simply do it programmatically

Comment: I vote for this one because it's the simplest one and it's not perfect but good enough.

Answer (score 0):

For button you use below code

```
btn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1
btn.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
btn.titleLabel?.lineBreakMode = .byClipping
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: These options don't exist for buttons.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I just do that once and it will work for all buttons?

Comment: @narb What do mean by all buttons? It will work in every device. Just try it. If you facing any issue then let me know.

Comment: @dahiya_boy I assume I do it on a per button basis? how do you init btn? Associate a btn with an outlet?

Comment: @narb Actually I didnt understand your last comment. Where u facing issue?

Comment: what is btn in btn.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 1? how do you initialize it?

Comment: @dahiya_boy Seems like a good answer. But I think you should delete the whole `UILabel` thing, or at the least make very clear that this IB method does not apply here. At the moment your answer is rather confusing.

Comment: @meaning-matters thnks for suggestion,

Answer (score 0):

```
if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 480 {
    // iPhone 4
    mybutton.titleLabel.font = mybutton.titleLabel.font.fontWithSize(20)
} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height == 568 {
    // IPhone 5
    mybutton.titleLabel.fontt = mybutton.titleLabel.font.fontWithSize(20)
} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 375 {
    // iPhone 6
    mybutton.titleLabel.font = mybutton.titleLabel.font.fontWithSize(20)
} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 414 {
    // iPhone 6+
    mybutton.titleLabel.font = mybutton.titleLabel.font.fontWithSize(20)
} else if UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width == 768 {
    // iPad
    mybutton.titleLabel.font = mybutton.titleLabel.font.fontWithSize(20)
}
```

Comment: Everywhere in the code I use a button, I need to do that? There is no global setting?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Device Pod for checking the Device.
https://github.com/Ekhoo/Device
After That

```
 switch Device.size() {

        case .screen3_5Inch:

       myButton.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: YourfontName, size: 20)
        case .screen4Inch:
            myButton.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: YourfontName, size: 22))
        case .screen4_7Inch:
            myButton.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: YourfontName, size: 23)
        case .screen5_5Inch:
            myButton.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: YourfontName, size: 25)
        case .screen5_8Inch:
            myButton.titleLabel?.font =  UIFont(name: YourfontName, size: 28)
        default:
            print("Unknown size")
        }
```